# How to get around the error "Failing because 'fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled" with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to query the 5 first elements of my table "Product" in my database (and then the 5 next etc.) in Spring Data using `Pageable`. But my table "Product" contains a relationship with another table named "Company" so I need to do a `join fetch` to get the companies information too.

I have the error `Failing because 'fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled`. I think I understand why it does this error, it's because I can't do a `join fetch` on a query to put in a `Page` because this could contains millions of rows.

Anyway, I'm learning these technologies and I'm looking for a way to make it work. How can I fetch the companies information if I'm putting the result of the query on "Product" in pages ?

Here's how I do it in my ProductRepository.java :

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select distinct product from Product product left join fetch product.companies",
        countQuery = "select count(distinct product) from Product product")
    Page<Product> findAllWithEagerRelationships(Pageable pageable);
}
```

And in my ProductRessource.java :

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public List<Product> getAllProducts(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean eagerload,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int limit,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int offset) {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Products");

    if (limit != 0) {
        return productRepository.findAllWithEagerRelationships(PageRequest.of(offset,limit)).getContent();
    } else {
        return productRepository.findAllWithEagerRelationships();
    }
}
```

My Product.java contains :

```
@ManyToMany
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "product_company",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Company> companies = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: See this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-query-fail-on-pagination-over-collection-fetch/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so thanks to SternK's comment, I figured out that maybe, it wouldn't be a very good idea just to disable the `hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch` setting. So [as mentioned](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/) in a linked article, I tried to fix the Hibernate error with two SQL queries that can fetch entities in read-write mode.

Here is how I did it with my Spring repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select product.id from Product product order by product.id",
                countQuery = "select count(product.id) from Product product")
    Page<Long> getProductIds(Pageable pageable);

    @Query(value = "select distinct product from Product product left join fetch product.companies where product.id in (:listProducts) order by product.id",
            countQuery = "select count(distinct product) from Product product")
    List<Product> findAllProducts(@Param("listProducts") List<Long> listProducts);
}
```

I have two `@Query`. In the first one I only select ids and put them into a `Page<Long>`. In the second one I do my `left join fetch` on my companies and pass the list of product ids via the `@Param("listProducts)` annotation.

In my REST controller I have this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Transactional
public class ProductResource {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean eagerload,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int limit,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") int offset) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Products");

        List<Long> productIds = productRepository.getProductIds(PageRequest.of(offset,limit, Sort.by("id").ascending())).getContent();
        return productRepository.findAllProducts(productIds);
    }
}
```

So I catch the result of my first query (`getProductIds`) in a `List<Long>` and pass this list as a parameter of the second query (`findAllProducts`).

Hope it helped someone else :)

Comment: Thanks.  worked great and I didn't need to use my brain to figure it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Nicryc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9090969/nicryc)

I added this part as I needed the Pagination as a result and not a List.

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public Page<Product> getAllProducts(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean eagerload,
                                    Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get all Products");

    Page<Long> productIds = productRepository.getProductIds(pageable);
    List<Product> list =  productRepository.findAllProducts(productIds.getContent());
    return new PageImpl<>(list, pageable, list.size());
}
```