# How to find all with eager relationship with specification and pagable in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `product` and `kind` object with Many To Many relationship. I can get products with eager relationship by:

```java
  @Query(
    value = "select distinct product from Product product left join fetch product.kinds",
    countQuery = "select count(distinct product) from Product product"
  )
  Page<Product> findAllWithEagerRelationships(Pageable pageable);
```

or products by specification and pagable by:

```java
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Page<Product> findByCriteria(ProductCriteria criteria, Pageable page) {
    log.debug("find by criteria : {}, page: {}", criteria, page);
    final Specification<Product> specification = createSpecification(criteria);
    return productRepository.findAll(specification, page);
  }
```

But when I try to combine them to one,

```java
  @Query(
    value = "select distinct product from Product product left join fetch product.kinds",
    countQuery = "select count(distinct product) from Product product"
  )
  Page<Product> findAll(Specification<Product> specification, Pageable pageable);
```

I got error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch. In memory pagination was about to be applied. Failing because 'Fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled.
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get around the error "Failing because 'fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled" with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64956134/how-to-get-around-the-error-failing-because-fail-on-pagination-over-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the temporary solution. I changed `@ManyToMany` annotation in entity class to

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
```

then my code work exception. Try this if you want. But I'm not sure about performance with this solution. I need to confirm it.

Update: This solution can resolve load data problem but I will not able to edit data