# Issue with Join Fetch Hibernate query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new using hibernate join fetch queries and would like some help on the below matter.
I have one Entity that has quite a few OneToMany associations. And in the rest call
I need to load all of those associations to prepare the result.

I was using Jpa findAll(Pageable) method however on production seeing huge load on read queries. I understand that I ran into N+1 problem which I am trying to solve however getting bellow error:

```
   {
  "title" : "Internal Server Error",
  "status" : 500,
  "detail" : "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch. In memory pagination was about to be applied. Failing because 'Fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled.; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch. In memory pagination was about to be applied. Failing because 'Fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled.",
  "cause" : {
    "title" : "Internal Server Error",
    "status" : 500,
    "detail" : "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch. In memory pagination was about to be applied. Failing because 'Fail on pagination over collection fetch' is enabled."
  }
}
```

====================
using Running with Spring Boot v2.5.4, Spring v5.3.9 and mysql 5.7
Here is my code snippet:

Entity:

```
package com.pitstop.catalogue.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.pitstop.catalogue.util.EligibleOffer;
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A Product.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "category_id";
    public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE = "unit_price";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = PRODUCT_NAME, length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(name = "description", length = 200)
    private String description;
    
    private Long brandId;

    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "product_icon_url", length = 500)
    private String productIconUrl;

    @Column(name = PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE)
    private Double unitPrice;

    @Column(name = "gst_rate")
    private Double gstRate;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "part_no", length = 45)
    private String partNo;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "serial_no", length = 45)
    private String serialNo;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "unit_type", length = 45)
    private String unitType;

    @Column(name = "line_item_id")
    private Long lineItemId;

    private Long categoryId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product"}, allowSetters = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    private Set<Offer> offers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product"}, allowSetters = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    private Set<ProductAttributes> productAttributes = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product", "productModel"}, allowSetters = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    private Set<ProductModelMapping> productModelMappings = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"product"}, allowSetters = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    private Set<ProductSeller> productSellers = new HashSet<>();

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "tag", length = 50)
    private String tag;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Instant created;

    @Column(name = "created_by", length = 100)
    private String createdBy;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getProductIconUrl() {
        return productIconUrl;
    }

    public void setProductIconUrl(String productIconUrl) {
        this.productIconUrl = productIconUrl;
    }

    public Double getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(Double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public Double getGstRate() {
        return gstRate;
    }

    public void setGstRate(Double gstRate) {
        this.gstRate = gstRate;
    }

    public String getPartNo() {
        return partNo;
    }

    public void setPartNo(String partNo) {
        this.partNo = partNo;
    }

    public String getSerialNo() {
        return serialNo;
    }

    public void setSerialNo(String serialNo) {
        this.serialNo = serialNo;
    }

    public String getUnitType() {
        return unitType;
    }

    public void setUnitType(String unitType) {
        this.unitType = unitType;
    }

    public Set<Offer> getOffers() {
        return offers;
    }

    public void setOffers(Set<Offer> offers) {
        this.offers = offers;
    }

    public Set<ProductAttributes> getProductAttributes() {
        return productAttributes;
    }

    public void setProductAttributes(Set<ProductAttributes> productAttributes) {
        this.productAttributes = productAttributes;
    }

    public Set<ProductModelMapping> getProductModelMappings() {
        return productModelMappings;
    }

    public void setProductModelMappings(Set<ProductModelMapping> productModelMappings) {
        this.productModelMappings = productModelMappings;
    }

    public Set<ProductSeller> getProductSellers() {
        return productSellers;
    }

    public void setProductSellers(Set<ProductSeller> productSellers) {
        this.productSellers = productSellers;
    }

    public Long getLineItemId() {
        return lineItemId;
    }

    public void setLineItemId(Long lineItemId) {
        this.lineItemId = lineItemId;
    }

    @Transient
    public double getSellingPrice() {
        // As discussed with Rohit, iterate over all the valid offers (by date)
        // and then apply which has the highest discount value. This is for Pitstop offers only.
        // Sellers offers will be created by sellers.
        if (this.offers.size() > 0) {
            Double sellingPriceFromOffers = EligibleOffer.apply(this.offers, this.unitPrice);
            return sellingPriceFromOffers;
        }
        return this.unitPrice;
    }

    @Transient
    public double getProductUnitPrice() {
        return this.unitPrice;
    }

    @Transient
    public double getProductGstRate() {
        if (callSellers() != null && callSellers().size() > 0) {
            ProductSeller productSeller = callSellers().get(0);
            return productSeller.getGstRate();
        }
        return gstRate;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<ProductSeller> callSellers() {
        //sorting products by seller price in ascending order
        List<ProductSeller> sellers = new ArrayList<>();
        sellers.addAll(productSellers);
        Collections.sort(sellers, (Comparator.comparing(ProductSeller::getUnitPrice)));
        return sellers;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Instant getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Instant created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Long getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(Long brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", brand=" + brandId +
                ", productIconUrl='" + productIconUrl + '\'' +
                ", unitPrice=" + unitPrice +
                ", gstRate=" + gstRate +
                ", partNo='" + partNo + '\'' +
                ", serialNo='" + serialNo + '\'' +
                ", unitType='" + unitType + '\'' +
                ", lineItemId=" + lineItemId +
                ", category=" + categoryId +
                ", offers=" + offers +
                ", productAttributes=" + productAttributes +
                ", productModelMappings=" + productModelMappings +
                ", productSellers=" + productSellers +
                ", tag='" + tag + '\'' +
                ", created=" + created +
                ", createdBy='" + createdBy + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    List<Product> findAllByCategoryId(Long categoryId);

    List<Product> findAllByBrandId(Long brandId);

    @Query(value = "select p " +
            "from Product p " +
            "left join fetch p.productAttributes productAttributes",
    countQuery = "select count(p) from Product p")
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045141/1056042) answer?

Comment: I have fixed that issue and getting results properly. however query is taking longer to execute that before. any thought ?